# Markdown text editor code, table, list not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, r-markdown

I want to write my blog post with markdown editor, my problem is when I publish my post edit with markdown then code block, list item, table, and so on not working properly, another part is works file like image, link, text bold...

looks like:

[image]

And output is:

[image]

I have tried code by this way:

`posts.js` file

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import matter from 'gray-matter'
import { sortByDate } from '@/utils/index'

const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join('posts'))

export function getPosts() {
  const posts = files.map((filename) => {
    const slug = filename.replace('.md', '')

    const markdownWithMeta = fs.readFileSync(
      path.join('posts', filename),
      'utf-8'
    )

    const { data: frontmatter } = matter(markdownWithMeta)

    return {
      slug,
      frontmatter,
    }
  })

  return posts.sort(sortByDate)
}
```

`[slug.js]` file:

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import matter from 'gray-matter'
import marked from 'marked'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Layout from '@/components/Layout'
import CategoryLabel from '@/components/CategoryLabel'

export default function PostPage({
  frontmatter: { title, category, date, cover_image, author, author_image },
  content,
  slug,
}) {
  return (
    <Layout title={title}>
      <Link href='/blog'>Go Back</Link>
      <div className='w-full px-10 py-6 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md mt-6 md:grid-cols-6'>
        <div className='flex justify-between items-center mt-4'>
          <h1 className='text-5xl mb-7'>{title}</h1>
          <CategoryLabel>{category}</CategoryLabel>
        </div>
        <img src={cover_image} alt='' className='w-full rounded' />

        <div className='flex justify-between items-center bg-gray-100 p-2 my-8'>
          <div className='flex items-center'>
            <img
              src={author_image}
              alt=''
              className='mx-4 w-10 h-10 object-cover rounded-full hidden sm:block'
            />
            <h4>{author}</h4>
          </div>
          <div className='mr-4'>{date}</div>
        </div>

        <div className='blog-text mt-2'>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: marked(content) }}></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join('posts'))

  const paths = files.map((filename) => ({
    params: {
      slug: filename.replace('.md', ''),
    },
  }))

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
  const markdownWithMeta = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join('posts', slug + '.md'),
    'utf-8'
  )

  const { data: frontmatter, content } = matter(markdownWithMeta)
  return {
    props: {
      frontmatter,
      content,
      slug,
    },
  }
}
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Tailwind CSS itself hides the list decoration by default, you should [enable it explicitly](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/list-style-type).

Comment: @pan93412 please can you tell me where I should change.

Comment: I'm not sure how to set up a class for a `marked` element. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

See: https://nextjs.org/blog/markdown

You need to setup: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography

Then add the `prose` class to your div that contains the markdown

```
<div className='blog-text prose mt-2'>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: marked(content) }}></div>
</div>
```